# FileSystemObject: what is the difference between GetFolder and GetParentFolderName?

Tags: filesystemobject

In FileSystemObject, what is the difference between GetFolder and GetParentFolderName?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One gets the folder the object is referencing, the other gets the folder that contains the folder your object is referencing.

```
Folder A
   - Folder B

GetFolder("Folder B") returns "Folder B"
GetParentFolder("Folder B") returns "Folder A"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to FileSystemObject from VBScript then there is no GetParentFolder method. *On the other* hand there is a GetParentFolderName method. Given a filename, the GetParentFolderName method returns a string value representing the folder that the file is in; whereas, the GetFolder method will return the a Folder object.